# How do you remove a vector? c++

Tags: c++, vector

I currently have a zombies project that I've been given for uni but I'm stuck on a couple of things.

How to properly remove a vector? We have zombies and pill objects that are stored in vectors. My first thought was to change the symbol but obviously that doesn't work since that's all I was changing like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXPILLS; i++)
{
    //if pill coordinates = spot coordinates
    if ((pills.at(i).y == sp.y) && (pills.at(i).x == sp.x))
    {
        pills.at(i).symbol = TUNNEL;    //make pill a tunnel
    }
}
```

This pill object needs to be completely removed instead. I have to do this also for when a zombie falls down a hole (`sp` is an instance of the zombie class).

How can I remove it all together?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Where are you trying to remove the vector from?

Comment: if you mean removing items **from** a vector then look at the `erase` function

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete a particular element of the vector?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`std::vector::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) already?

Comment: Basically when if ((pills.at(i).y == sp.y) && (pills.at(i).x == sp.x)) happens our character is ontop of a pill and the only way I could figure out how to remove that pill (think pacman) was to do pills.at(i).symbol = TUNNEL; (TUNNEL in this case is a blank space)

Comment: I had a look at erase but the program just kept crashing, I thought it would be this pills.erase(pills.begin());

Comment: Possibly you forgot to decrease `MAXPILLS`, and you accessed the last element *after* you deleted one.

Comment: Please try to post necessary code parts first, else you won't get a precise answer to your related crash problem etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm instead:

```
pills.erase(std::remove_if(pills.begin(), pills.end(), [&sp](const decltype(pills.at(0)) &p){return p.x == sp.x && p.y == sp.y;}));
```

Note that I'm using lambda function here which is C++11 construct so you might want to check whether you're allowed to use that in your assignment first and replace it with functor object if you're not allowed to use C++11.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm trying to recreate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chBP95GsG80 with that code the remove_if flags up saying namespace "std" has no member "remove_if"?

Comment: you have to include `<algorithm>` first ;-)